# Trouble passing a state set array as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-component

[image]I'm fetching data from an API that returns an object that has a drink object array that has one item. And I'm having trouble passing the array to a child component function.

```
<Modal.Body className={'d-flex flex-row'}>
        <CocktailDetailsList drinks={cocktailDetails?.drinks[0]}/>
</Modal.Body>
```

I'm calling the API from useEffect() and setting the value the api returns inside of a useState constant.

```
    const [cocktailDetails, setCocktailDetails] = useState<CocktailDetails>();
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/my_key/lookup.php', {
            params: {
                i: props.id
            }
        }).then(res => setCocktailDetails(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
```

How do I pass the array drinks to the child component?

Comment: The issue I'm having is I don't want to list every item in the array as a prop as I don't want an enormous list of items as that wouldn't be as clean.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue on my local but having some trouble. can you please share the screenshot of api response in console?  or what's in props.id?

Comment: I updated the post with the coctailDetails console log

Comment: props.id contains a property called idDrink

Comment: I don't see any drinks property inside state cocktailDetails (in the image you shared). But you are passing it to the child component ```drinks={cocktailDetails?.drinks[0]}```.  can it be the cause of the issue? or am I missing something?

Comment: Drinks is in the object returned by the API. I know because I used postman. The object looks like {drinks: [{}]}

Comment: if it's an array of objects being returned from the API (and is a property of cocktailDetails state), you can directly pass the it like this ```<CocktailDetailsList drinks={cocktailDetails?.drinks}/>``` to child component. 
But if it is coming from any other API, I'll recommend to store it in a separate state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242792/discussion-between-pdrake1988-and-ankit-saxena).